# ORM 'like' query in django python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

**keywords=Donut** working with **`keyword__name__in=Donut`**
but i need to get result  **`keyword__name__in=Don`**

**views.py**

```
items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],keyword__name__in=keyword,keyword__mood__moods=mood).select_related() 
# items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],keyword__name__contains=keyword,keyword__mood__moods=mood).select_related() # it is returning null
# items=ItemVariation.objects.filter(item__restaurant__id = i['restaurant']['id'],keyword__name__icontains=keyword,keyword__mood__moods=mood).select_related()
```

**models.py**

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500,unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='keywords/', blank=True, null=True)
    mood=models.ManyToManyField(Mood,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class ItemVariation(models.Model):
    restaurant=models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    item_code=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    keyword= models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes/', blank=True, null=True)
```

i have this query i need to use **keyword__name__in= %keyword%** as a like

i'm using **PostgreSQL** database
parameter that i'm passing for this */?keywords=Donut&mood=Dating*

result when i'm using **keyword__name__in**

```
"items": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "item": {
                    "name": "Donut",
                    "short_description": "Donuts"
                },
                "price": 0,
                "item_code": "test",
                "image": "/media/dishes/download_3_kcE78IS.jpeg",
                "restaurant": 1,
                "keyword": [
                    3
                ]
            }
        ],
```

result when i'm using **icontains**

"items": [],

Comment: Please share the (relevant) models.

Comment: Then it is `keyword__name__icontains=keyword`.

Comment: icontains is not working it is returning empty

Comment: Add sample data and keyword value to your question.

Comment: But here you thus look whether the `item` has a restaurant for which the `keyword__name` contains the text, and *for that* keyword, it contains a specific mood.

Comment: I have update question i'm getting result when using keyword__name__in=Donut but i need to find result from keyword=Don

Comment: Please add full filter code with `icontains`

Comment: check in view i have edit my filter query but icontains and contains are not returning any response

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#contains) (or `icontains`)

```
keyword__name__contains=keyword
```

Comment: @M4STER - "not working" isn't much of a description.